# How to clear Zookeeper corruption

Tags: hadoop, solr, cluster-computing, apache-zookeeper

I am looking for some help in figuring out how to clear what looks like a corruption in Zookeeper.  Our setup was running fine with Solr Cloud.  At some point the root partition on one of the cluster nodes became full and the system went down.  After we brought it back up, Solr was not responding and could not start.

It looks like there is a corruption in the zookeeper data.  Anytime a client tries to access the node /overseer/queue it will kill the connection with an error:

> ..."KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /overseer/queue"

Opening up the zk client shell allows us to list other nodes, but if we try to delete/list/clear/etc on the /overseer node it will fail with this error.

Are there any manual steps that could be done to clear this out?  Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Also it looks like there are over 200k child nodes under the /overseer/queue node.  Maybe this has something to do with it, but we can't delete the child nodes if we can't even list them out.

Comment: What is the structure of your SolrCloud? Can you restart the total cloud again?

Answer (score 2):

The Zookeeper database isn't corrupt, but zookeeper has a limit on the maximum response size, and listing 200k children of a znode exceeds this max response size.

To work around this, you can set [jute.maxbuffer](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperAdmin.html#Unsafe+Options) to a large value to let you list and delete the nodes under queue.  You need to update this setting on all the servers, and the client you are using to clean up.

There is an open bug to fix this, [ZOOKEEPER-1162](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-1162) .